# Is there a bound of $\Delta(x)$ related to Riemann prime-counting funtion?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis, distribution-of-primes

$$\Delta (x)=\left(\pi (x)-\operatorname {R} (x)+{\frac {1}{\ln x}}-{\frac {1}{\pi }}\arctan {\frac {\pi }{\ln x}}\right){\frac {\ln x}{\sqrt {x}}},$$
where $\operatorname{R}(x)$ is Riemann R function.

[This page](http://www.primefan.ru/stuff/primes/table.html#theory) furtherly talks about $\Delta(x)$ and shows a plot of it:

[image]

And it seems true that $|\Delta(x)|\le c$ for some constant $c$. However, I searched for that and failed. Is that true ?

Comment: It's probably true, but this would be a much stronger result than the Riemann Hypothesis

Comment: @jjagmath It is untrue by some theorems on the growth of $\psi(x)-x$ under the RH saying that it can't be $=O(x^{1/2})$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449960/littlewoods-1914-proof-relating-to-skewes-number but I can't find a good reference.